# Impersonating caller prevents connection to database (not an obvious permissions issue)

Tags: wcf, impersonation

I have a web service hosted in IIS running under a domain account which also has permissions to a SQL Server. All the users mentioned below have access to this SQL Server.

Here is a fragment of the service config:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
<binding name="SecureWebBinding">
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
<transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
```

... etc.

During a particular service method, I make one call to the database as the service account and wish to make another as the user who called the service (we are returning a FILESTREAM transaction context created by the calling user - these are user-specific). The first call completes but the second is wrapped as follows:

```
using (ServiceSecurityContext.Current.Impersonate())
{                    
   using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...Integrated Security = true...)
   {
      connection.Open(); //<---Exception
```

After the call to `Impersonate`, `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` correctly returns the calling user rather than the service account with `ImpersonationLevel == Identification`.

If I remove the first 2 lines, the operation completes as the identity of the service account. Of course the later call to FILESTREAM subsequently fails.

Comment: This appears to be an issue of Impersonation vs Delegation, as the SQL Server is on another box. So, how the %#$@ do I delegate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup an SPN for the server to DB as its using kerberos when you are impersonating.  But it depends on the error message you are getting.  This resource should help you, although im still running into issues for a similar process, but your process seems like it should work with this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/12/02/understanding-kerberos-and-ntlm-authentication-in-sql-server-connections.aspx